# Grails: Setting the length of a NUMBER column?

Tags: grails, mapping, column-sizing

I'm trying to tell Grails to create columns of a specific length.  This works great for strings, however, for columns of NUMBER type, no matter what I try it keeps creating the default NUMBER(10,0) size.  I've tried:

```
static mapping {
  field(precision: 2)
}
```

I've also tried:

```
static mapping {
  field(size: 2)
}
```

Am I missing something?  Is this possible?

Comment: Try using the `max` and `min` constraints instead. Something like `field(min: 0, max: 99)`.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
static mapping = {
  field length: 2
}
```

You should have tried one last time with `length`. :-) Refer [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either (I probably tried it too, just forgot :)).  It's still creating a NUMBER(10,0) column.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **constraints** in Grails.
Example :

```
class User {
    static constraints = {
        age min: 18, max: 60
    }
}
```

Check out the official Grails document about constraints : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#constraints

Answer (score 0):

```
  static mapping = {
       field column: 'field',sqlType: 'NUMBER(14,0)'
     }
```

Works when dealing with Oracle database.

Though the post is late it might be useful for future reference.